# How to handle an input parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a code to change values in Fahrenheit to Celsius using Javascript.

```
<p id = "result"> </p>      // The result will appear here

<script>
function toCelsius(f) { 
    return (f-32) * 5/9;
} 
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = toCelsius(77);
</script>
```

I checked this code, and it works on my Eclipse.
However, instead of putting the value directly, I want to input a number in Fahrenheit and change that into Celsius.

I added the following.

```
<form id="frm1">
Enter a number :  <input type="text" name=fahrenheit> <br>
<input type=button" onclick="toCelsius(frm1)"  value="change">  // I need some help for handling parameter here
</form>
```

I want to make it as simple as possible like below. 
[image]

Could anyone give me some tips on how to handle an input parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I spotted a few problems.

1. There were some syntax issues in writing HTML attributes
2. The code that changes `innerHTML` of result won't get invoked when the button is clicked. Rather, it'll get invoked only once, the first time the script is run. To fix this, I placed that line in a function which would be called when the button is clicked. Please look at the `change` button action.

```html
<p id="result"></p>

<script>
  function toCelsius(f) {
    return (f - 32) * 5 / 9;
  }
  function changeClicked() {
    var input = document.getElementById("fahrenheit").value;
    if (parseInt(input) === null) return;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = toCelsius(input);
  }
</script>

<form id="frm1">
  Enter a number : <input type="text" id="fahrenheit" name="fahrenheit"> <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="changeClicked()"  value="change">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an event listener for the button then call your `toCelsius()` function with passing the input value to it.

```js
function toCelsius(f) {
  return (f - 32) * 5 / 9;
}
document.getElementById('btn_change').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var fahrenheit = document.getElementsByName('fahrenheit')[0].value;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = toCelsius(fahrenheit);
});
```

```html
<form id="frm1">
  Enter a number : <input type="text" name=fahrenheit> <br>
  <input type="button" id="btn_change" onclick="toCelsius(frm1)" value="change">
</form>
<p id="result"> </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Give input tag an id of "number"
Enter a number :  <input type="text" name=fahrenheit id ="number"> <br>

// Then,

<script>

  let number = document.getElementById("number").value;
  function toCelsius(f) { 
     return (f-32) * 5/9;
  } 
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = toCelsius(number);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- The result will be displayed here -->
<p id="result" style="min-height: 20px"></p>

<input type="number" name="fahrenheit">
<input type="button" class="convert-to-celsius-btn" value="Convert to C">

<script>
var convertBtn = document.querySelector(".convert-to-celsius-btn");
var fahrenheitInput = document.querySelector("input[name=fahrenheit]");
var resultEl = document.querySelector("#result")

function toCelsius(f) {
  return (f-32) * 5/9;
}

function convertToCelsius() {
    var fahrenheit = fahrenheitInput.value;

  // input validatation code goes here ...

  // next convert to celsius
  var celsius = toCelsius(fahrenheit)

  // now show the value in the DOM
  celsius = celsius.toFixed(2);
  resultEl.textContent = celsius + " C"
}

convertBtn.addEventListener("click", convertToCelsius);
</script>
```